# Java: sending intents to different activities

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-intent

I'm creating a google maps application and I need to send over ALL the information of the markers which the user has created. However, i do not want to open the activity afterwards, only send the data and then open the activity through a separate button. Any suggestions to how i should approach this issue?

here is the code where the marker is created, and sent over to the other activity, but i don't want to start the activity that is receiving the info :(

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == GET_DETAILS) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            List<MarkerOptions> markers = new ArrayList<MarkerOptions>();

            String marker_title=data.getStringExtra("title");

            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
                    .title(marker_title);
            Marker m = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            markers.add(markerOptions);

            MarkerOptions[] markersArray = markers.toArray(new MarkerOptions[markers.size()]);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MarkerListActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("markers", markersArray);
            startActivity(intent);

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat, lon)));

        }
    }
}
```

Also, another thing, what does the code:

```
List<MarkerOptions> markers = new ArrayList<MarkerOptions>();
```

do? I'm new to java and programming so I'm unsure why there are TWO data structures rather than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not getting what is the point of `Intents` for this case. `Intents` are used to start one `Activity` from another (among other things). As you say, you can pass data to the `Activity` that is about to be started in the `Intent` if the data is going to be needed by the `Activity` that is about to start. It seems to me that you want to send the data to the `Activity` via the `Intent` so every `Activity` instance of that class gets that data. It does not work that way. The data you send via the `Intent` is not "saved" for all instances of the `Activity`, so starting a **new** `Activity` via a `Button` at a later time, will not be able to access the data that was sent on a previous `Intent`.

In short, it seems that the `Intent` mechanism is not what you want for what you are trying to do. It looks like you want the `Marker` to be persisted in a `SharedPreference` or a `Database`, so then every instance of any `Activity` can get the data.

Comment: ahh i understand now, thanks for your detailed response !

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Comment: would it be okay for you to answer a quick question that I wrote at the end of this post? List<MarkerOptions> markers = new ArrayList<MarkerOptions>(); <---- why are there two data structures? what do the <> represent? and what does this output?

Comment: There is only one data structure, a `List`. `List` is an interface that defines how the concept of list should operate in Java. `ArrayList` is an implementation of a `List` that is backed by an array.  You have other implementations of `List` like `LinkedList`. The interface, as with any interface, hides the implementation details from the consumer. The `<>` is called the `diamond` operator. It is how you tell the `List` what type of object it will contain. Look into [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for more information.